# Обработка ошибок в PHP

Tags: php

Достаточно ли этих настроек, чтобы за обработку ошибок не болела голова?

```
error_reporting (E_ALL);  
ini_set ('display_errors', 'off');    
ini_set ('error_log', 'log.txt');    
ini_set ('log_errors', 'on');
```

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то нет. Сделайте лучше [обработчик ошибок](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) внутри кода. А внутри этого хендлера уже пишите что за ошибка и стектрейс с аргументами (классы желательно не разворачивать, разве что маленькие). Это как минимум.